# Efficiency of a nested for() loop

Tags: java, ajax

I'm working on a web-based scheduling application where users are given a page with a schedule and data table. The schedule component acts as the input for placing a reservation but also displays all the current reservations across multiple users. The data table contains a list of rooms, and is selectable so that rooms can be checked/unchecked. I'd like to use ajax so that as I select/de-select a room, reservations tied to that room will appear/disappear in my schedule.

Right now I'm using an ajax listener on my data table to trigger the following:

```
for(reservation item:items){
    for(Rooms r:selectedRooms){
        if (r.getRoom().equals(item.getRoom())) {
            //Code for adding/removing event to schedule
        }
    }
}
```

Where the app goes through each selectedRoom value and compares it with the room value from all reservation records. If a reservation has a room value matching the current selectedRoom, then an event will be added to the eventModel for that record.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this comparison without having to use the nested for-for-if loop? Depending on the number of records in a given month or week, I'm wary of the resources this ajax listener could eat up.

Comment: Where from do you get `items`? Database? Maybe querying only for selected rooms would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about performance impacts, you should always start by measuring. Without measuring you don't know whether your worries are justified and even if you're certain they are, you don't know what (if any) effect your attempts to improve performance will have.

That said, if the nested loop really causes a problem, what you can do is copy all the rooms in `selectedRooms` into a `HashSet` first, and then only iterate across the items, checking whether the set contains `item.getRoom()`. (Or you can do it the other way around, creating a hash map from `items` with `Room` keys and reservation items as values.)

*The saving here comes from the fact that a lookup in a hash map/set is much faster than iterating across all the elements, searching for equality. The price you pay for this is that you have to construct your set/map from the list first, which takes time and memory.*

*So you have to make a decision on whether the price is worth paying for what you get. And this demonstrates why measuring is so important.*

Comment: I agree that measuring performance is the best practice to follow with loops. However, this application was hard to measure only because I don't have an idea of how many reservations will be coming in per month. Previously, the for loop was set to run through all reservation records, but I've now limited the loop to only go through reservations with a start date after the current datetime.

Answer (score 3):

You could create and maintain a `Map<Room,Reservation> reservedRooms = new HashMap<>();` map. You can then merely use:

```
 for(Rooms r:selectedRooms){
    Reservation reservation = reservedRooms.get(r);
    if ( r != null ) {
        //Code for adding/removing event to schedule
    } else {
        // Handle case where room is not currently reserved.
    }
}
```

I would like to stress *you will need to maintain this structure*!

Remember to ensure that `Room` has effective and consistent `equals` and `hashCode` implementations as these are used extensively in `HashMap`.

Comment: You really should mention about caveats having custom object as a key in the map.

Answer (score 1):

While I would actually recommend using a `Map <room, reservation>` if you are stuck with the way they are currently implemented I would ask if they are 1 to 1. If they are, I would do something like:

```
for(reservation item:items){
    for(int i = 0; i < selectedRooms.count(); i++){
        if (selectedRooms[i].getRoom().equals(item.getRoom())) {
            //Code for adding/removing event to schedule
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This would save you at least a little bit of processing, but otherwise you can't really do this anymore efficiently. That being said, java 8 can make it more pretty, and even run it in parallel.

Comment: No need for a variable here, just use `break;`. Or is your intention to `break;` after `found = true;` (eliminating the need for the `!found` check in `for)`, and then `if (found) break;` at the end of the outer `for` loop?

Comment: `break;` works, I just generally use a variable because in some languages `break;` won't break out of the `for` loop, just the `if` statement.

Comment: Huh? I don't know any language where `break` only breaks out of an `if`. Which language does this?

Comment: For some reason I thought I ran into this in Basic (I learned basic many years ago), but after looking into it I am wrong completely. That being said, I modified my comment to show this accordingly.